Problem running EXE with Windows Forms via Process.Start() in DLL loaded dynamically by Console application
Title:
Problem running EXE with Windows Forms via Process.Start() in DLL loaded dynamically by Console application (C#, .NET Framework 4.5.2)
Description:
I am developing a Console application in C# (.NET Framework 4.5.2) that dynamically loads a DLL (also developed by me) using Reflection. Inside this DLL, there is a method that uses Process.Start() to run an EXE file that contains a Windows Forms interface. However, when I call this method via Reflection, the EXE starts, but the Windows Forms interface does not appear.
Console Program Code:
// Example of the code that loads the DLL
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("MyDLL.dll");
Type type = assembly.GetType("MyNamespace.MyClass");
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("MyMethod");
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
method.Invoke(instance, null);

DLL Code (relevant snippet):
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        // Processing before starting the EXE
        var startExe = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startExe.FileName = "PathToMyExecutable.exe";
        startExe.Arguments = "\"arg1\" \"arg2\" \"arg3\"";
        startExe.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startExe.CreateNoWindow = true;
        Process.Start(startExe);
    }
}

The Problem:

The DLL code is executed correctly (I verified with log messages), the executable starts, but the EXE's window with the Windows Forms interface does not appear when the method is called via Reflection by the Console program.
I don't receive any exceptions or errors, the window simply doesn't show up.

What I’ve tried:

I’ve researched several solutions, and some mention using ProcessStartInfo with UseShellExecute or CreateNoWindow options, but it didn’t solve the issue.
I tested calling the EXE outside the Reflection scenario (directly from another context), and the EXE's Windows Forms interface shows up normally.
I also tested loading the same DLL from a non-.NET program (e.g., C/C++), and the EXE and its window appear correctly, so I suspect the issue is related to using Reflection in the Console application.

Constraints:

The Console project cannot have a direct reference to the DLL. The DLL is loaded dynamically via Reflection.
The Console application should not have prior knowledge of the DLL or the EXE.

Question: Is there any limitation or specific configuration when using Process.Start() in a DLL loaded via Reflection that would prevent the EXE’s window with Windows Forms from appearing? How can I ensure the EXE runs correctly and its window is displayed?
Additional information:

.NET Framework 4.5.2
The DLL is loaded, and its methods are executed without errors, the EXE is started, but the Windows Forms window doesn’t appear.
I’ve already tried setting ProcessStartInfo with various options like UseShellExecute = true, WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal, without success.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Try to move the code from the dll into the main module then execute without any reflection and other tricks. Will it work? What if you will run your winforms app via the command line (cmd.exe)? And can you please remove the WindowStyle=Hidden from the code in the sample as it is confusing?

@Serg I changed the ProcessStartInfo settings to make the window visible, and I discovered that there was an error occurring in the EXE being called. However, since the Process was not handling the ErrorOutput, the calling application didn't handle the error either. That was the reason why nothing was being displayed when the EXE was called via Reflection from the Assembly.
